# Different views in Apple maps and MKMapview for same place

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, apple-maps

Hi I have integrated MKMapView map in my iOS application. Apple maps show different view for one place and MKMapview shows different view for same place. How can I get clear view with zoom level like Apple maps.

[This is the Apple maps view screenshot link](http://imgur.com/PS7nftd)

[This is the MKMapView map screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lknkD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it's look like the same place. But issue it you map has less zoom level.

Reduce you span value to make it more zoom. So you will get the same result. Try to solve by error and trial. you can check the below code to set span value of the map.

```
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta =  0.4;  
span.longitudeDelta = 0.4;     
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
region.span = span;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

Comment: Hello already I tried. It shows tiles when changes the span in MKMapview. But in Apple maps it shows clear view. And also the views were different compared to Apple maps. Please look two screenshots.

Comment: can you provide lat,long for which you are trying this?

Comment: Address is 45153 Cougar Cir, Fremont, CA, United States.

Latitude and Longitude is 37.5127326,-121.9134644